# Understanding an inequality involving the norm of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality, polynomials

In the proof below of [1, Lemma 1.1], the author asserts that

$$ \sum | c_i B^i | \leq \sqrt{d} ||w(xB)|| $$

Here $w(x) = \sum_i c_i x^i$ is a polynomial with degree $d$ and $B$ is a positive integer. The polynomial norm is defined as $||w(x)||^2 = \sum_i c_i^2$.

**Question:** Can someone explain how the $\sqrt{d}$ term appears? It seems to me that the LHS is *equal* to the RHS (by the definition of polynomial norm), so I must be missing something.

Here is the complete context in case I omitted anything:

[image: proof of Lemma 1.1]

References:

[1]: Boneh, "Finding smooth integers in short intervals using CRT decoding", available at https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/CRTdecode.html

Comment: Divide both quantities by $d$. The inequality is then a direct consequence of the fact that an arithmetic mean is less than or equal to the corresponding quadratic mean. Equality holds only if all the terms are equal. See, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean.

Comment: @dfnu Aren't both quantities sums, though? Where would the product come in?

Comment: You are probabily thinking about geometric mean, not *quadratic mean*?

Comment: @dfnu D'oh, of course! I should have written out the RHS explicitly, would have been obvious then. Thanks for your help!